# Address already in use when importing file in python

Tags: python

I have a python server to which I can do POST requests. This is the script

```
from bottle import Bottle, run, template, get, post, request

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/rotation', method='POST')
def set_rotation():
    rotation = request.forms.get('rotation')
    return rotation

run(app, host='localhost', port=8080)
```

So in the POST request I send the rotation value and get that in the script. I need the *rotation* value in another script so I do this in that script

```
from mybottle import set_rotation

print set_rotation
```

When I run the first script and then the second script, I get this error

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I'm quite new to python so I don't have a clue as to what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You have another service listening to port 8080 (it could be your own server if you tried to run it more than once).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to import without starting the run function use 
 `if __name__=="__main__"`

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    run(app, host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Each time you import  from the file  `run(app, host='localhost', port=8080)` is going to be executed, using  `if __name__=="__main__"` will only start the server when you execute the file itself so you will avoid your `socket.error: [Errno 98]` which you are getting trying to start the server when it is already running.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what the problem is and how I can solve it. The error makes sense now and the scripts are working exactly like I want them to!

Answer (score 1):

You should verify that no other program use the `8080` port, or simply change the port to another value.

I think you run the server twice. The error you get comes from the second server that can't bind on port `8080` because the first is already using it.

Your code, as given, will start a server when imported. This is probably not what you want.

You can avoid this behavior by test the name of your module, which is `__main__` only if it's the called script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(app, host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Then, when imported, no server is ran.